# В каком потоке выполняется асинхронный код?

Tags: c#, async-await

```
async Task MyMethod()
{
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("...");
}
```

Вопрос: В каком потоке запускается метод httpClient.GetAsync("...") ? в текущем или в другом потоке из пул потоков ?

Comment: Он возвращает `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`, следовательно `Task` выполняется асинхронно в потоке пула потоков.

Comment: @AlexKrass Task - это не обязательно cpu bound нагрузка и она не обязательно требует поток для выполнения. Async await как раз сделан для того, чтобы код из вопроса можно было выполнить в одном потоке (включая весь код внутри GetAsync, если там есть await, но нет ConfigureAwait(false)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код до GetAsync, включая вызов этого самого GetAsync, отрабатывает в том потоке, в котором был вызван ваш метод. Начало GetAsync отрабатывает в том же потоке.

Никаких переключений потоков вообще не происходит до тех пор, пока не произойдет реальная асинхронная операция (где-то внутри GetAsync).

После начала реальной асинхронной операции GetAsync возвращает управление, не дожидаясь ее окончания, и только на начале ожидания (await) поток освобождается.

По завершению операции продолжение метода GetAsync (парсинг результатов) и продолжение вашего когда, который с этими результатами работает, будет выполнено или в первоначальном потоке, или в потоке из пула, в зависимости от контекста синхронизации.

Comment: по идее код `GetAsync` начнет выполнение в том же потоке, где был вызван, до первой асинхронной операции, а в каком потоке закончит выполнение - зависит от того, установлен ли контекст синхронизации для текущего потока.

Comment: @tym32167 да, насколько я понял, под "запускается" тс подразумевает "будет вызван"